# How to measure command/script execution time in xonsh?

Tags: xonsh

How do I measure execution time of command/script in xonsh? In bash I can do it with `time` eg:

```bash
> time sleep 1

real    0m1,002s
user    0m0,001s
sys     0m0,001s
```

How to do it in xonsh?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no shell builtin `time` in `xonsh`.  I use [time(1)](https://linux.die.net/man/1/time), which is usually installed in most linux distros, but should be available in your package manager.

```
  time sleep 1
0.00user 0.00system 0:01.00elapsed 0%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 2048maxresident)k
0inputs+0outputs (0major+100minor)pagefaults 0swaps
```

or if you want it to more closely match the output of the bash builtin

```
  time -p sleep 1
real 1.00
user 0.00
sys 0.00
```

or you can roll your own (for wall time)

```
 import time
 from contextlib import contextmanager
 @contextmanager
°º def _time():
°º     tic = time.time()
°º     yield
°º     print(time.time() - tic)
°º
 with _time():
°º     sleep 1
°º
1.013087511062622
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know there's package to install called "time" (in Linux Manjaro at least) :)